Nespresso machine stuck in closed position with mangled capsule inside
Cant pull the lever up. No used pods. It happened when i tried to use a new pod and the used pod holder was full. We emptied it and put the slightly mased new capsule back in and closed the lid. It is now stuck closed.

Can you please update your question with what model Nespresso machine?  is it stuck completely closed, or there is a little bit of movement before it jams?
